# joining 2 table and bringing particular record at top

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, left-join, sql-order-by

I have  2 tables. first table has lot of rows but second table has only either `1 or 0` record. If second table contains one record then that record of first table should come at top. if second table contains no record then all the record of first table should display.
first table:

```
DEPT:-
10  ACCOUNTING  NEW YORK
20  RESEARCH    DALLAS
30  SALES   CHICAGO
40  OPERATIONS  BOSTON
```

Second table

```
EMP:-
1000    Shruti  40
```

for eg if I join table then deptno 40 of dept table should come at top. I wrote below query and it is working

```
select d.deptno,d.dname ,d.loc,e.empno,e.deptno from dept d ,emp e where d.deptno= e.deptno(+) and d.deptno in(select deptno from emp)
UNION ALL
select d.deptno,d.dname ,d.loc,e.empno,e.deptno from dept d ,emp e where d.deptno= e.deptno(+) and d.deptno not in(select deptno from emp);
```

How can I modify above query so that all the record of `dept` table should display if table `emp` has no record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want a `left join` and a conditional sort:

```
select d.*, e.empno
from dept d
left join emp e on e.deptno = d.deptno
order by case when e.deptno is not null then 0 else 1 end, d.deptno
```

Depending on your data, you might be able to simplify this as:

```
order by e.deptno, d.deptno
```

This takes advantage of the fact that an ascending sort puts `null` values last.